# Java swing easy one but I don't know it

Tags: java, swing, window, builder

i'm new there. My first issue:
When i start my GUI java swing application in Window Builder, first object is always selected

[image: this]

and when i click anything (button or anything) it's show like it's clicked and i don't want it to show. What command for this?

[image: Unwanted thing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this:

```
button.setFocusPainted(false);
```

[java, swing, awt, remove focus from all objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404340/java-swing-awt-remove-focus-from-all-objects)

Comment: Thanks mate, but i have nearly 200 buttons in my application, is there a command to set every button focuspaint off?

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but a quick google search gave me this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422642/swing-remove-focus-border-from-dialogues-buttons

Comment: That works, thanks alot ;>